# Angular: need search bar working on 2 different ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic/Angular.

I have a search bar which I need to have it working in 2 different scenarios BUT at the same time. Look:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <!--here is the ng-model query-->
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query">
</label>
<!--here is the 1st filter:query-->
<div ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:query" ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
  <div>
     <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
   </div>
   <!--here is the 2nd filter:query-->
   <div class="item item-button-right"
        ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter:query"
        on-tap="goToLines(league)">
         {{league.name}}
   </div>
```

so, all I need is that when the user is searching for something, the search bar returns **sport.name** and **league.name**, is it clear for you guys?

**UPDATE***
this is the service where I am calling sports:

getSports: function(agent) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

```
LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS)
  .then(function(sports) {
    if (!_.isNull(sports)) {
      defer.resolve(_.values(sports));
    }else {
      $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/lines/sports/' + agent)
        .success(function(sports) {
          //forcing array instead of object
          sports = _.values(sports);
          sports = _.sortBy(sports, function(sport) {
            return sport.priority;
          });
          LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS, sports);
          defer.resolve(sports);
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          defer.reject(err);
        });
    }
  });
return defer.promise;
```

},

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @sholanozie if I remove the 2nd ```filter:query``` works perfect for ```sport.name```, but if I don't remove it, it only returns the ```league.name```

Comment: Can you please explain further. provide an example data array of  the sports with its corresponding leagues and an example of an search and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to search *either* field, drop the second filter and use the special `$` to traverse the object hierarchy. See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for more info.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.sports = [
    {name: 'Basketball', leagues: [{name: 'Mens'}, {name: 'Womens'}]},
    {name: 'Volleyball', leagues: [{name: 'Mens'}, {name: 'Womens'}]},
    {name: 'test', leagues: [{name: 'test'}]}
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query">

    <div ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:{$: query}" ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
      <div>
         <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
       </div>

       <div class="item item-button-right"
            ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues"
            on-tap="goToLines(league)">
             {{league.name}}
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I mean, there is the mistake, if you type test, the searcher returns test on sport.name, and also on league.name, but if you search a sport, lets say Basketball, then the searcher only returns sport.name and not league.name. What I want is that if you search sport.name, then the searcher returns sport.name along his leagues (league.name), and if you search only for on league, then the searcher has to return both again.

Comment: I understand your requirements now. Updated my answer.

Comment: actually works in your example but not in my code with the real information. look at this Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/2Z5SMlANCGd3r4Trfwzm?p=info where I am extracting the real JSON with the real information running on my app. and it is not working. @adam0101

Comment: That's because you only have one big object as a single element in an array in that example. Can you change the JSON to be an array of objects instead?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2Z5SMlANCGd3r4Trfwzm?p=preview look at it now. But I do not know to do what you are asking me.

Comment: hey @adam0101 look at the update I did to my question. There is the service.

Comment: Your JSON is one giant object with each property referencing a child object, like a dictionary. If you want to iterate over those properties you can do that, but you'll need to change your ng-repeat to start with `(key, sport) in sports`. However, I don't think you can use the `$` with an object like that so you would have to use a custom filter in the ng-repeat. It would be easier if you could change the JSON to be an array with each object being an entry in the array instead of each object being a value of a property. If you can do that, then you should be able to follow my example.